# Recyclerview and OkHttp request synchronisation

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, okhttp, synchronization

I'm trying to fetch some data from LastFm API, process it, and display it in a recycler view. My problem is that because of the way my code is structured I think that I initialize my recycler view before data is fetched so nothing is being shown until I reopen my fragment and I don't know how to fix that.

Here is my fragment code:

```
public class TopArtistsFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ArtistRecyclerViewAdapter adapter;
    private TopArtistsViewModel mArtistsViewModel;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mArtistsViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(TopArtistsViewModel.class);

        mArtistsViewModel.init();

        mArtistsViewModel.getArtists().observe(this, new Observer<ArrayList<ArtistData>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(ArrayList<ArtistData> artistData) {
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_top_artists, container, false);
       recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.artistRecyclerView);

       return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        initRecyclerView();
    }

    private void initRecyclerView() {
        adapter = new ArtistRecyclerViewAdapter(mArtistsViewModel.getArtists().getValue(), getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

This is my ViewModel:

```
public class TopArtistsViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private MutableLiveData<ArrayList<ArtistData>> mArtists;
    private ArtistDataRepository mRepo;

    public void init() {
        if(mArtists != null)
                return;
        mRepo = ArtistDataRepository.getInstance();
        mArtists = mRepo.getArtists();
    }

    public LiveData<ArrayList<ArtistData>> getArtists() {
        return mArtists;
    }
}
```

And this is my repository where the work is being done:

```
public class ArtistDataRepository {
    private static ArtistDataRepository instance;
    private ArrayList<ArtistData> dataSet = new ArrayList<>();

    public static ArtistDataRepository getInstance() {
        if(instance == null)
            instance = new ArtistDataRepository();
        return instance;
    }

    public MutableLiveData<ArrayList<ArtistData>> getArtists() {
        setArtists();

        MutableLiveData<ArrayList<ArtistData>> data = new MutableLiveData<>();
        data.setValue(dataSet);
        return data;
    }

    private void setArtists () {
        fetchData();
    }

    private void fetchData () {
        final String requestUrl = "https://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=chart.gettopartists&api_key=2124b8e156db20ac7a5035fad9c01b8e&format=json";

        final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(requestUrl).build();
        Call call = client.newCall(request);
        call.enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull IOException e) {
                Log.d("NETWORK FAILURE", "Artist fetch");
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull Response response) throws IOException {
                if(response.isSuccessful())
                    parseData(response.body().string());
                else Log.d("OKHTTP", "Response not successful");
            }
        });
    }

    private void parseData (String queryResponse) {
        try {
            JSONArray artistResponse = new JSONObject(queryResponse).getJSONObject("artists").getJSONArray("artist");

            for(int i = 0; i < artistResponse.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject artist = artistResponse.getJSONObject(i);

                dataSet.add(new ArtistData(artist.getString("mbid"), artist.getString("playcount"), artist.getString("listeners"),
                        artist.getString("name"), artist.getJSONArray("image").getJSONObject(0).getString("#text")));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm just a beginner so right now I'm basically trying to merge code from different tutorials into one. That's why some things you see here probably don't make sense, so please do tell me what I can fix.

Comment: try not to put your API_KEY here

Comment: Don't worry, it isn't really a working key, I remembered that in the last second so I just changed a couple of numbers. Stupid solution.

Comment: at first use AsyncTask to call request then init your recycler view when you put all data in your arraylist then init it. I mean in the **OnResponse** method after parseData  and if you got error send the logcat message too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to answer the question, part of the solution is, like someone suggested, to add adapter.setData() function to my adapter and call it in onChanged().

```
 mArtistsViewModel.getArtists().observe(this, new Observer<ArrayList<ArtistData>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(ArrayList<ArtistData> artistData) {
              -->  adapter.setData(artistData); // Something like that 
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

The second part was adding data.postValue() in parseData function in my repo

```
private void parseData (String queryResponse) {
    try {
        JSONArray artistResponse = new JSONObject(queryResponse).getJSONObject("artists").getJSONArray("artist");

        for(int i = 0; i < artistResponse.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject artist = artistResponse.getJSONObject(i);

            dataSet.add(new ArtistData(artist.getString("mbid"), artist.getString("playcount"), artist.getString("listeners"),
                    artist.getString("name"), artist.getJSONArray("image").getJSONObject(0).getString("#text")));
        }
        data.postValue(dataSet); //THIS WAS ADDED
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This probably isn't the optimal solution for what I'm doing here, but it works as intended.

Answer (score 1):

In order to tell the Recycleview that the data has come you need to get the Adapter and set its data then call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

```
 mArtistsViewModel.getArtists().observe(this, new Observer<ArrayList<ArtistData>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(ArrayList<ArtistData> artistData) {
              -->  adapter.setData(artistData); // Something like that 
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Tried that, nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

[Got through this link](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/retrofit-android-example/)

first try to learn how to fetch data using retrofit and you won't to parse data their is a library GSON and Moshi which will do all your work you just need to use POJO. Just go through this example

Comment: OkHttp is better but you must use whit AsyncTask .